# Calabash test getting response 0 scenarios 0 steps 0m0.000s

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash-android

I am new to android and calabash, trying to test the android app using Calabash . And I have followed this [doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/introduction-to-calabash/#Behavior_Driven_Development) for the setting up. And **my_first.feature** file contains the sample code

```
Feature: Running a test

Scenario: Register
Given I am on the Welcome Screen
Then I touch "SKIP"
Then I wait
Then I should see Registration Screen
```

I have used the latest apk(buid after making changes within the **.feature** file) to run the test and for this I am getting the response

```
* features/support/env.rb

Features:

0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
```

I did not make any changes apart from the my_first.features file content.
It would be great if some body help me figure out the issue and fix it.

Comment: How are you trying to run the scenarios?  It'll make a difference to the answers you get.

Comment: Thank you Alannichols for the helping hand. I fixed the issue by running the test being outside the feature file.

Comment: Please don't cross post. You asked the same question on the calabash-android forum.  We monitor both these channels.  When you cross post you waste our time.

Comment: I just got the answer from calabash-android-forum , I have posted the answer here to make solutions available for others  in future without going and search the forum. I am really sorry if I waste your valuable time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running the Calabash test for the first time after creating the feature file the test should be run from the directory  immediately above the features folder.